# A question on rank-nullity.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an idempotent matrix. (i.e. $A^2=A$). We need to show that
$$\operatorname{rank}(A-I)=\operatorname{nullity}(A).$$

I tried to find a map from $\operatorname{range}(A-I)$ to $\operatorname{null}(A)$ but got confused somewhere in the middle.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the fact that $A(A-I)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea seems good, but the map you're looking for is easier than you think.

If $v\in \operatorname{null}(A)$, that is $Av=0$, then $v=(A-I)(-v)$, so $v\in\dots$

Conversely, if $v=(A-I)w$, then $Av=A(A-I)w=\dots$

Comment: That actually was so simple. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The general proof involves reduction of $A$.

In characteristc 0, you can just write
 $$A^2 = A,\\
(I-A)^2 = I-A$$
and then 
$$
rank(A-I) = rank(I-A) = tr(I-A) = n- tr(A) = 
\dim\ker A
$$

Comment: The rank-trace equality holds only in characteristic $0$.

Comment: the general proof involves reduction of $A$.

Comment: The general proof requires no reduction, nor trace.

Comment: well, you answer consists in some kind of reduction.

Comment: @mookid What reduction? I see none, just a consideration of two subspaces.

Comment: This is what I call some kind of reduction. of course it is very elementary in this case, but still...